Can I use my Military time served and rank achieved to increase my net worth accreditation?
I heard that someone who has military experience can use their time served and rank achieved to list in their net worth accreditation.  Is this true? and if so, how does it work? and how do I figure out the amount to list in my net worth?

What's "net worth accreditation"?

I tagged this as united-states because it appears to be an entirely US concept. Basically, you tell your investment fund you're rich and they let you have access to various investment opportunities that are unavailable to the general public.

It might help if you told us where you heard this. It's possible you are being set up for a scam where someone will offer to "help you qualify for this" for an ever-escalating set of fees, in which case you would want to cut off contact with that person and report the attempted swindle.

Why do you want to become an accredited investor in the first place? Is there some specific reason you want to invest in something other than stocks, bonds, and mutual funds?

This is not true. The SEC lists the criteria by which an individual can attain net worth accreditation here:

How can individuals qualify as accredited?
Individuals (i.e., natural persons) may qualify as accredited
investors based on wealth and income thresholds, as well as other
measures of financial sophistication.
Financial Criteria

Net worth over $1 million, excluding primary residence (individually or with spouse or partner)
Income over $200,000 (individually) or $300,000 (with spouse or partner) in each of the prior two years, and reasonably expects the same for the current year

Professional Criteria

Investment professionals in good standing holding the general securities representative license (Series 7), the investment adviser representative license (Series 65), or the private securities offerings representative license (Series 82)
Directors, executive officers, or general partners (GP) of the company selling the securities (or of a GP of that company)
Any “family client” of a “family office” that qualifies as an accredited investor
For investments in a private fund, “knowledgeable employees” of the fund



There's no such thing as "increasing your net worth accreditation." Either you meet the eligibility criteria to be an accredited investor or you don't - it's not something you can increase or decrease.
Also, military service or rank have no bearing on this. Your net worth is computed exactly the same way whether you were a private, captain, general, or never served at all. Either way, you calculate your net worth by adding up the value of your assets and subtracting your debts. (Obviously, I'm oversimplifying a little bit, but military service or rank doesn't affect your net worth).
Also, I would encourage you to consider why you want to become an accredited investor in the first place. All this does is allow you to invest in certain things that are considered high risk, such as hedge funds and certain types of private equity. Unless you meet the eligibility requirements listed in the other answer (such as being high net worth), you probably wouldn't even want to invest in these things - those kinds of products are simply not suitable for most individual investors. Is there some specific reason you want to invest in something other than stocks, bonds, ETFs, and mutual funds? For most individual investors, "boring" investments like index funds are your best investment.
Personally, I have two basic rules of investing:

I'm not very smart or particularly good at investing. There's no way that I'll be able to beat the professionals (or the market as a whole).
If I start thinking that I'm smart or good at investing, refer to rule #1.

Many of the times I've gotten in trouble in investing were times when I was trying to be smarter about it than I actually am.
